# Change keyboard shortcut to "Run Script" in Atom IDE

Tags: python, windows, ide, atom-editor

In the "Script" package, The keyboard shortcut to "Run Script" is `shift+ctrl+b`.
Does anyone know how to change this to a custom shortcut?

I have script 3.14.1 installed in Atom (with Windows 10 64bit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

go to "*Settings*", "*Packages*", find the "*script*" package and click "*Settings*".

at the top, select "View Code" button.

[image: view script code]

In the new window that pops up, expand the "*keymaps*" folder and open the "*script.cson*" file.

Find the shortcut for `'script:run'` (line 15) and type in your preferred shortcut.

Save the file.

That's it!

[image: script code]

Comment: Still ctr-b triggers 'fuzzy-finder:toggle-buffer-finder'. Is it because of native! ?

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer (from **mark jay**) didn't work for me. What worked is using the `keymap.cson` of the atom editor:

[image]

And there just add, e.g. (to run with Alt-R):

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'alt-r': 'script:run'
```

[image]

Then it was working just fine. You can similarly modify any other Atom shortcuts here too.